# Bootstrap Carousel w/ Centered div and multiple divs showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So in short I need something exactly like "Centered Mode" in this plugin

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

[image]

I need to do this but using bootstrap. As lead would like to avoid using plugins where possible. Unless it would be simpler to just use a plugin.

The lead dev on the project I am on wants to avoid adding plugins where possible. We are using bootstrap 3 and he figured the carousel that comes with bootstrap could just be edited to do what we need. Would it be more time efficient to try and edit the carousel, or build something from scratch(which at point wouldn't it just make sense to use a plugin?)

My only idea would be to have a div, with a bunch of inline divs that are translated on click. Would that be the right approach?

Or is there an easy way to manipulate the built in carousel?

Codepen for where I am at so far.

http://codepen.io/OMGDrAcula/pen/eJjgwN

```css
h2{
    margin: 0;     
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 90px;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-family: "trebuchet ms", sans-serif;    
}

.item{
    background: white;    
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}

.carousel{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bs-example{
 margin: 20px;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .item {
  opacity:0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* ie fix */
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.item {
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* ie fix */
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Carousel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="6500" data-ride="carousel">
     <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>   
       <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item col-lg-3 carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 1</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>First slide label</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item col-lg-3 carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 2</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                  <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item col-lg-3 carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 3</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                  <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be quite easy for you to create a similar effect with bootstrap. You can edit the CSS of the carousel elements to give the effect that you want. The left and right arrows are also available out of the box, and can be manipulated to provide the visuals you want. Good luck!

Comment: I have been messing with it, but get stuck. I added a fiddle to where I am at right now.

Comment: Ok mate, I will have a look :)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. It needs to be responsive, which probably goes without saying. I had them all in line up to 6 but they moved very goofy. Not in a line. The next one would just jump to a position instead of flowing nicely. I appreciate the help

Comment: sburke0708 I am trying to take the bootstrap default carousel and make it like the "Center Mode" of slick which I linked as well.

Think of it like this

D D O D D 5 divs the O is centered and on click left or right the next D becomes the centered but they all have to be showing on the screen at same time.

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/L3d67v65/7/

```
<!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail"> 1 </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail"> 2 </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail"> 3 </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail"> 4 </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--/row-->
              </div>
              <!--/item-->
              <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail"> 5 </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail"> 6 </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail"> 7 </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail"> 8 </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--/row-->
              </div>
              <!--/item-->
            </div>
            <!--/carousel-inner-->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#slideCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#slideCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
```

Had a look. For the short time I spent this quick fiddle should be enough to get you started. I have aligned the carousel elements in bootstrap rows and the arrow buttons will change the row you see. After styling the thumbnails I have started to look like the one in your example, you should make a start on trying to make just one element stand out as active as opposed to a whole row by adding CSS to the active class. I hope this gets you on the right track :)

Comment: Awesome thank you so much I will take a look at it! I appreciate all the help!

Comment: My pleasure. Hope you manage to get it looking how you want it!